# How to refresh images in every second in windows 7 phone

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7.1

i am showing images from server. In server image is changing in every second. I want that in my application image should be change automatically after one second.M new in windows 7 programming. Kindly suggest me where i am lacking in concept. M using this code.
This process will start when i will tab on my image.

```
private void image1_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1000); // 500 Milliseconds
            dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
            dt.Start();


        }
```

This is calling this method .

```
 void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    status.Text = "chking" + counter++;

    // Do Stuff here.
            image1.Source = null;
            Uri imgUri = new Uri(base_url,UriKind.Absolute);
            BitmapImage BI = new BitmapImage(imgUri);
            int H = BI.PixelHeight;
            int w = BI.PixelWidth;
            image1.Source = BI;
   }
```

In this code my Counter is working fine and status.Text is sucessfully change in every second. But image is changing once after that its not changing. 
Kinldy suggest me where i am commiting mistake.

Thanks in advance
Gaurav Gupta

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(); as a member variable instead of declaring it in the images tap event.

Comment: Did you make sure that the dt_Tick runs every 1000 miliseconds either way? (with a debug text)

Comment: int H = BI.PixelHeight;
            int w = BI.PixelWidth; is never used

Comment: Try binding the image.source in xaml, and creating a property for it in c#

Comment: int H and int W hav another use that i dont mention in this code. i used one textblock for chking that dt_Tick is working after 1000 ms , its working fine. status.Text is updating every second. but image is not changing. Can i use web browser to show the image?

Comment: Don't use a webbrowser for this... this should work, we are just missing something.... I don't know how the URI looks like, so try: Uri imgUri = new Uri(base_url,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing when grabbing images from a camera in my wp8 app. I hold the URL including the current datetime-value as a url-param in my viewmodel. When i want to refresh, i just reset my URL-property.

Here's my sample:
this.MyUrlProperty = string.Format("{0}?timestamp={1:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff}", _originalCameraUrl, DateTime.Now);

Works great for me...